# Using Azure API Management service, is it possible to have 2 different Authentication approaches in place?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

For example, Is it possible to have the native subscription based authentication and OAuth2 such that either one of these can be used for authenticating any given request?

At present, I have subscription based approach on the API frontend, but am interested in moving to OAuth. Id like to however keep clients who have been configured to use the subscription based approach unchanged if possible.

perhaps the answer is that , I must stick to 1 and only 1.

But feel this is worthwhile to ask since perhaps others may start with subscription based approach, and interested in moving towards an alternative.

Once solution I feel might be to create a seperate API front end for OAuth2, which points to same backend. That would satisfy the problem. However, Im hoping to keep the same api frontend. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible since if you won't pass the subscription key or pass an invalid one it will deny the request.

What you can do is use versions, so let's say v1 uses subscription key and v2 uses another authentication mechanism. So in summary, you'll duplicate all API's, but for v2 you won't assign a Product (won't require the subscription key).

Comment: I like this idea very much. Didnt necessarily think of using the versions as the separator. I only thought of creating an entirely new API. Using the same API is definitely very attractive! Thank you!